# Converting $f_{2}$ to $O(f_{2})$ that isn't $f_{1}$

Tags: functions, algorithms

So the actual problem I'm trying to figure out is Find functions $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ such that both $f_{1}(n)$ and $f_{2}(n)$ are $O(g(n))$, but $f_{1}(n)$ is not $O(f_{2})$

I know that if I had $f(n) = n^{2} + 4n$ that I would have $g(n) = n^2$, but I'm not sure if that makes $O(f(n))$ the same thing or not. If it does, then can I get a hint on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the idea here is to find three functions of different growth rate. We want $f_2$ to be the slowest and $g$ to be the fastest. Does something like this work?

$f_1 = x^2$ and $f_2 = x$. Then, both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are $O(x^3)$, but $f_1 \neq O(f_2)$.